# Why not all request headers are available in AngularJS request interceptor's config parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS $http interceptor to intercept requests and responses.
I need to access few of the request headers in the interceptor's request method.

But when I console logged the config object received as an argument to request method, I could see only single header under config.headers; that is

`Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"`

and the developers' tool is showing all the request header like

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:mr,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:61917
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:61917/index.html
```

I know `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common` sets headers that are common for all requests, and the default header added is

`Accept: application/json, text/plain, * / *`

But why can't I access other request headers for the request?

How can I get hold of all these request headers in request interceptor method in AngularJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the other header values as browser settings that are added while constructing the request. You can get some of those like [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.referrer), [`window.navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent) or [`window.navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage.language).

Comment: So, we can't access those headers in AngularJs. I was particularly interested in `Accept-Language`, but the `navigator.language` is not a dependable option to read it (IE). So seems like there is no way to get it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try something like `var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;`? It should work in IE too.

Comment: No, not working. It gives the system language not the language preferred in Internet Options > Languages. http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/save-way-to-detect-browser-language.99655/

Answer (score 3):

I can answer this!  Even though your browser sends the `Accept-Language` header in it's request to the server, only the server can read the value of this header (crazy, right?).  The only way to access the value of this header is to read the value of the request header on the server and then send it back to the client.

You can send the value of `Accept-Language` back in the response headers or in the response body.

Additionally, somewhere on your server there will be a line that says something like:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "Content-Type,Origin"
```

It might help to add `Accept-Language` to that list of exposed headers, so it reads like this:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "Content-Type,Origin,Accept-Language"
```

I am using the `Accept-Language` header and not from `window.navigator.language` to figure out the user's language, because it seems like `window.navigator.language` often gives an incorrect value.

Hope that helps!